# Haproxy Bind Error

Tags: linux, tcp, proxy, haproxy, rhel5

Hi there StackOverflow,

I seem to have an error with my haproxy, this is what I get when I try and run it

```
[ALERT] 208/051346 (5865) : Starting proxy ah1: cannot bind socket
[ALERT] 208/051346 (5865) : Starting proxy ah2: cannot bind socket
```

I'm running this for a TCP proxy.

This is my config:

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Example configuration for a possible web application.  See the
# full configuration options online.
#
#   http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.3/doc/configuration.txt
#
#---------------------------------------------------------------------

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Global settings
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
    global
    log         127.0.0.1 local2 
    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     4000
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy
    daemon

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# common defaults that all the 'listen' and 'backend' sections will 
# use if not designated in their block
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
defaults
    mode        tcp
    log         global
    option      dontlognull
    option      forwardfor
    option      redispatch
    timeout connect 10000 # default 10 second time out if a backend is not found
    timeout client 300000
    timeout server 300000
    maxconn     60000
    retries     3


listen ah1 207.254.9.41:30000
mode tcp
balance leastconn
server ah1_1 46.16.77.23:30000

listen ah2 207.254.9.41:30001
mode tcp
balance leastconn
server ah2_1 46.16.77.23:30001
```

We're running Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 (x64)

Answer (score 7):

Check for already existing processes using ports 30000 and 30001:

lsof -i OR netstat -lnp

If you do not have anything listening on ports 30000 or 30001 then make sure that you have the ip address 207.254.9.41 actually configured on the system:

ip addr OR ifconfig

If you do not see 207.254.9.41 listed then you can either change it to the correct IP address or simply take the IP address off:

:30000 instead of 207.254.9.41:30000

If none of those fix it then I suggest upgrading to either 1.4 or 1.5 (I have been using 1.5 in a very large production environment for almost a year with no issues). If 1.4 and 1.5 are not in the package repositories then I suggest compiling yourself.

Comment: ":30000 instead of 207.254.9.41:30000" this helped me to get out of the issue of bind error. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

May be you are running apache on that server, it is using same port that you are using on Haproxy. then just stop application that you using same port you are using on haproxy then restart it. it should work.

thanks